# How to make placeholder text permanent and space between

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a text input like this where I have permanent text on the right and the replaceable text on the left

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. You can also target the elements with class names. I have added some width and padding to `input`. Change it as per your requirements.

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: grey
}

input {
 padding-right: 40px;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<label><span>bhat</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="0.00" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what @kiranvj said, I just added JS to hide and show the floating text depending on the input:

```js
function hideSpan(x) {
  document.querySelector('.fp').style.display = x.value !== "" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: grey;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<label><span class="fp">bhat</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="0.00" oninput="hideSpan(this)"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using position absolute span to the textbox.

```css
.input-with-txt {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 45px;
}


.input-with-txt > span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-with-txt">
  <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" />
  <span>baht</span>
</div>
```